# How can I make this div centered without also centering the text? I want it to be left aligned

Tags: html, css, centering

I'm a beginner in HTML/CSS and I'm stumbling my way through building my own Neocities site. I was able to get the div centered by putting  above and  below it, but (understandably) the text is also centered.

This is my code:

```html
<center>
  <div style="width:1000px;height:150px;border:1px solid blue;overflow:scroll;padding:15px 25px 15px 25px;background-color:#A2E4B8;color:#000000;scrollbar-base-color:#DEBB07;box-shadow: 7px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id
    venenatis a condimentum vitae. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. Amet luctus venenatis lectus
    magna. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet.
  </div>
</center>
```

[A screenshot of my Neocities HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh8xA.png)

I tried using text-align: left; but that didn't yield results. I am sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm feeling quite lost as to what that is.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center **is deprecated**. Use CSS instead. Also why don't you use a stylesheet instead of sticking spaghetti inline style?

Comment: i wasn't aware of that! i'll keep it in mind for the future. thank you so much for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Set the left and right margins to **auto**.

```css
.d1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
  background-color: #A2E4B8;
  color: #000000;
  scrollbar-base-color: #DEBB07;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="d1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet.</div>
```

Further reading [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using the "center" tag as it's deprecated in HTML5. Instead, use CSS to center the div container.

I've added CSS styling directly within the "head" section using the "style" tag, but you can use it in an external css file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Center div with flex</title>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    .content-container {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      overflow: scroll;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      background-color: #A2E4B8;
      color: #000000;
      scrollbar-base-color: #DEBB07;
      box-shadow: 7px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      text-align: left; /* Align the text to the left */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content-container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used flexbox on the body to center the content both horizontally and vertically. The div element got a classname ".content-container" and by using the "text-align: left;" it aligns the text within the "div" to the left while keeping the entire "div" centered on the page.

Or if you dont want to style the body element, here is an alternative method:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Center div with margin</title>
  <style>
    .content-container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      overflow: scroll;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      background-color: #A2E4B8;
      color: #000000;
      scrollbar-base-color: #DEBB07;
      box-shadow: 7px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="content-container">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.<br><br>Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Placerat vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Semper viverra nam libero justo laoreet.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the div with the classname ".content-container" is centered horizontally by using "margin: 0 auto;" and the text in it aligned left by using the "text-align: left;" property.

Answer (score 0):

Try `text-align:left !important;`

Comment: text-align does work! i'll be sure to test out what others have answered as well, considering the center tag is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

```
 ``<center>
  <div
    style="
      width: 1000px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
      overflow: scroll;
      padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
      background-color: #a2e4b8;
      color: #000000;
      scrollbar-base-color: #debb07;
      box-shadow: 7px 7px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      text-align: left;
    "
  >
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
    veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
    commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
    velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint
    occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
    mollit anim id est laborum.<br /><br />Fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus
    dolor purus. Id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Scelerisque in dictum non
    consectetur a erat nam. Ultrices eros in cursus turpis. Facilisi cras
    fermentum odio eu feugiat. Pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet
    venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. Amet luctus venenatis lectus magna.
    Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Nec dui nunc mattis enim ut
    tellus. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Placerat
    vestibulum lectus mauris ultrices. Semper viverra nam libero justo
    laoreet.
  </div>
</center>``
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).